# Android: ksoap2 org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41575240)

Tags: android

I've found many disccussions abouy this exception but none of them could help me.

I have a simple web service in .NET that returns a string without any parameter.
i have already tried it with another .NET application and it works fine.

I'm trying to make a call using ksoap2 with no success.
this is my class that makes the call to the web service:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.0.106:80/WebService1.asmx?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

public String Call()
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

          MarshalBase64 mbase = new MarshalBase64();
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER10);
  envelope.bodyOut = request;
  envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
  envelope.dotNet = true;
  envelope.implicitTypes = false;
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
  HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  mbase.register(envelope);
  Object response=null;

  try
  {
  httpTransport.debug=true;
  httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


  response = envelope.getResponse();
  }
```

The exception is thrown at `httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

any suggestions what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.tempuri.org/";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
```

Instead of:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
```